# Modify a service inside GitLab CI

Tags: elasticsearch, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm attempting to set up GitLab CI and I have some integration tests that run against elasticsearch. I'd like to install elasticsearch using the official docker image, so:

```
services:
  - elasticsearch:2.2.2
```

But I want the mapper-attachments plugin. I have had no luck adding a command in the `before_script` section to install the mapper-attachments plugin, because the elasticsearch files don't seem to be in the environment that the before_script section is running inside of. How can I modify the elasticsearch image that has been installed into the runner?

Answer (score 0):

You should create you custom elasticsearch container.

You could adapt the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:2.3
MAINTAINER Your Name <you@example.com>

RUN /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install analysis-phonetic
```

You can find this image on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tmaier/elasticsearch/).

Here are detailed steps:

- Register at https://hub.docker.com and link you Github account with it
- Create a new repo at Github, e.g. ["elasticsearch-docker"](https://github.com/tmaier/elasticsearch-docker)
- Create a Dockerfile which inherits `FROM elasticsearch` and installs your plugins ([see this example](https://github.com/tmaier/elasticsearch-docker))
- Create an [Automated build at Dockerhub](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) form this github repo (in my case: https://hub.docker.com/r/tmaier/elasticsearch/)
- Configure the Build Settings at Docker Hub

  - I added two tags. One "latest" and one matching the elasticsearch release I am using.
  - I also linked the elasticsearch repository, so that mine gets rebuilt when there is a new elasticsearch release
- See that the Container gets built successfully by Docker Hub
- Over at Gitlab CI, change the service to point to your new Docker image. In my example, I would use `tmaier/elasticsearch:latest`
- See your integration tests passing